# installing Node modules on Docker: why are they disappearing?

Tags: node.js, npm, docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to create my first node Docker image. It's for a hubot. Here's the basics of the `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
VOLUME /opt
COPY package.json /opt/hubot/
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install build-essential nodejs python
RUN npm install -g npm
WORKDIR /opt/hubot/
RUN npm install --prefix /opt/hubot/
COPY app /opt/hubot/app
```

The problem is that the node_modules don't exist after the build step is over. I can see that it is being placed in my expected location during the build step:

```
make[1]: Entering directory `/opt/hubot/node_modules/aws2js/node_modules/mime-magic'
```

So, I know Docker files are somewhat stateless, which is why "apt update && install" is necessary. But *something* gets left behind, otherwise the installed apt bits wouldn't be there at the end. How can I persist the `node_modules`?

Comment: Try removing the VOLUME declaration and give it a whirl.

https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/

Comment: @user2105103 ugh, that did it. I guess I didn't understand how VOLUME was supposed to work. Can you post that as the answer? I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changes made to VOLUMEs do not persist.

[Data Volumes](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/)

A data volume is a specially-designated directory within one or more containers that bypasses the Union File System to provide several useful features for persistent or shared data:

Data volumes can be shared and reused between containers

Changes to a data volume are made directly

**Changes to a data volume will not be included when you update an image**

Volumes persist until no containers use them